# install missing stack failed by apt-get ros-diamondback

Tags: ros, package

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I need to install gencam_cu package.
I found that gencam_cu package is belong to prairiedog stack.
http://www.ros.org/wiki/gencam_cu
How do I install prairiedog by using similar way like "sudo apt-get install ros-diamondback-prairiedog"
Because it said couldn't find ros-diamondback-prairiedog.
Thank you~

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9495/install-missing-stack-failed-by-apt-get-ros-diamondback/) by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2570 on 2011-03-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I assume there are no debian packages yet for prairiedog. You can check them out with svn, open a terminal and enter:

```
cd
mkdir ros
cd ros
svn co http://prairiedog.googlecode.com/svn/trunk prairiedog
export ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=/home/<your_username>/ros:$ROS_PACKAGE_PATH
roscd gencam_cu
rosmake --pre-clean --rosdep-install
```

This should do the trick.

---

Originally posted by [KoenBuys](https://answers.ros.org/users/134/koenbuys/) with karma: 2314 on 2011-03-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) on 2011-03-26**:
The export ROS_PACKAGE_PATH line allows you to "roscd gencam_cu". That line is only valid in the terminal you ran it in. You can add it to the bottom of your .bashrc (after the source /opt/ros... line) to have it be set for every new terminal opened after you update .bashrc.

**Comment by [KoenBuys](https://answers.ros.org/users/134/koenbuys/) on 2011-03-26**:
It calls rosdep install before make, see http://www.ros.org/wiki/rosmake, could you do $env | grep ROS and post it?

**Comment by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on 2011-03-25**:
what happened when I add --rosdep-install to rosmake? I found that when I open new terminal, I also can't able to roscd gencam_cu. Thank you~